# variable manipulation in Less

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

all
I want to calculate the height of the page ,and in my `test.less`

```
@clientHeight:`$(window).height()`;
```

when I use the `@clientHeight`,as jquery return just a number,I need to plus the unit like `px`
So,I tried these ways:
1)

```
div{height: @clientHeight+px;
```

It came out :
`height: 705 px;`
(Note that there's a space between them)
2)

```
@clientHeight:`$(window).height()+'px'`
```

It came out :
`height: "705px";`

Comment: I just found a trick tough it's not so elegant
`0px+@clientHeight`

Comment: Official documentation does have this example but they don't use the 'px' at the end.. So it's probably not needed. Is the height incorrect when you don't include 'px' at the end? Does compiled CSS have the 'px' appended for this property (is this the example with space between number and px)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this to trim off whitespace from the returned height value:

```
@clientHeight: `$.trim( $(window).height() ) + 'px'`;
```

(or dissect this if it won't be processed this way, sorry not using less.js, can't test it).

..or use plain `str.replace(' ', '');`

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been quite a long time, but if you or anyone else happens to be looking for an answer still, this worked for me:

```
@clientHeight: unit(`$(window).height()`, px);
```

From the LESS function reference:

> ### unit
>
> Remove or change the unit of a dimension

Comment: Does this not work when less is sent to the browser for compiling?

Answer (score 3):

I just found a trick tough it's not so elegant `0px+@clientHeight`