# Zoom/scale website content to fit browser area with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I coded a small website written in php, with a fixed 869px width to display properly in every screen. I also would like to integrate it to other pages with different width, which is sometimes wider then the original size.

I tried some solutions, but none of them seems to working cross-browser or does not scale the content within the wrapper. I am also trying with the viewport property but I had no success.

I am looking for some cross-browser jquery script that uses the zoom effect of the browser to fit the content to the browsing area. I have a div in the body called wrapper, and I would like to scale it and the content in it, like I do it with the CTRL + keys in the browser.

Comment: I will code my further projects with relative sizes, to prevent situations like this :) But I have to finish this in a short time

Comment: The closest thing you can get to in controlling scale is to use the meta viewport tag. Which may not work well enough in all cases.

Comment: I need to use it on desktop environment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap to scale your content (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). If you want to adjust the font size as well you can build with LESS or use plain javascript (e.g. using JQuery).

You can wrap your page into a

```
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

that scales automatically on various standard resolutions. You can adjust the width by overriding the bootstrap.min.css. A guide on how to enable responsive features can be found here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

You can add `row-fluid` class divs and use `span` classes to align your content. More information on how to use the grid system: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

For LESS I can recommend their homepage: http://lesscss.org/

And this is an older StackOverflow post that illustrates how to insert variables from JavaScript: [variable manipulation in Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920131/variable-manipulation-in-less)

Maybe using LESS is already enough for your needs.

Comment: I am very tempted to start flagging "just use Bootstrap" *answers* as spam.

Comment: Why? He wants his content to be scaled properly and reliably on every screen? Why shouldn't he use a design framework that supports reposnive scaling? With Bootstrap's reponsive features the website would scale to the available space. The other problem is the font size which is easily controlable via jQuery. So what is the problem?

Comment: Some tutorial about bootstrap scaling would be nice.

Comment: Here you go: This explains the responsive functionality (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive), this explains the fluid grid (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) and here is an example page that scales properly (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html). This scales the font size with jQuery (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window)

Comment: LESS might also be of interest for your project as it gives you the possibility to adjust the CSS content dynamically (http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: @Fred Yes, because Bootstrap is the only possible way to do that */sarcasm* (you could not pay me enough money to use TB in any project, I consider it to be that bad).  Give a man a fish and he eats for the day.  Teach a man to fish and he eats for the rest of his life.

Comment: You're right. It's not the only framework. But it's widely used and very well documented which results in a good learning curve. I don't see any reason to be so negative about my answer just because you have personal aversions regarding TB. Jameson said that there is only a short time to finish that project. That's why I suggested it.